# ORDER BY strings (can be numbers or strings) putting empty strings last MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, string, numbers, sql-order-by

I have a problem ordering a table.

I have a column of strings. These strings can be numeric (integer).

Now I want to order by ascending, leaving numbers on top and strings at the bottom, with the empty ones last:

```
12
23
28
33
Hello
Hello again
(empty string)
(empty string)
```

This is the problem, if I go with:

```
ORDER BY column ASC
```

this happens:

```
(empty string)
(empty string)
12
23
28
33
Hello
Hello again
```

I tried with:

```
ORDER BY CAST(column as unsigned) ASC, column ASC/DESC
```

but it puts number values at the bottom:

```
Hello again
Hello
(empty string)
(empty string)
(empty string)
12
23
28
33
```

How may I solve that? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
order by 
case 
when column is null then 1 else 0 
end, 
column
```

OR

```
  ORDER BY ISNULL(column), column ASC;
```

OR

```
  ORDER BY if(column = '' or column is null,1,0),column
```

Comment: Thank you but the empty strings are not null, but just empty "". So this solution doesn't work.

Comment: Change the case to `when column = '' then 1 else 0`. Does that work?

Comment: Yes it does, thank you. Anyway the third solution by Abhik does work too.
Thanks both of you.

Comment: @PhatWrat yes this should also work. here is a fiddle of both versions http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fff86b/4